# How to find logical layout of tk widget?

Tags: windows, tcl, tk-toolkit, ttk

I am learning ttk in depth and want to know how to find logical layout for any widget. Right now just exploreing and doing small experiments. In following code trying to show text but layout details are not documented for checkbutton.
So question arised for me how to find them for any widget easily.

---

[This Ttk style guide](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html) is really nice reference but not helping in layout in depth.
Thanking you.

```
ttk::style element create pin vsapi EXPLORERBAR 3 {
  {pressed !selected} 3
  {active !selected} 2
  {pressed selected} 6
  {active selected} 5
  {selected} 4
  {} 1
}
ttk::style layout Explorer.Pin {Explorer.Pin.pin -sticky news}
pack [ttk::checkbutton .pin -style Explorer.Pin]
```

Comment: Good luck. I have to read the source code to find that out…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the style in use for a given widget use the `winfo class` command:

```
% ttk::checkbutton .b
% winfo class .b
TCheckbutton
```

You can then dump the layout using `ttk::style layout`:  (reformatted for readability)

```
% ttk::style layout TCheckbutton
Checkbutton.padding -sticky nswe -children {
    Checkbutton.indicator -side left -sticky {}
    Checkbutton.focus -side left -sticky w -children {
        Checkbutton.label -sticky nswe
    }
}
```

This declares the elements and how they are to be placed. So to replace the `indicator` element you can copy this layout to define a new layout that references your new element:

```
% ttk::style layout Pin.TCheckbutton {
  Checkbutton.padding -sticky nswe -children {
    Checkbutton.pin -side left -sticky {}
    Checkbutton.focus -side left -sticky w -children {
      Checkbutton.label -sticky nswe
    }
  }
}
% place [ttk::checkbutton .pin -text text -style Pin.TCheckbutton] -x 10 -y 10
```

[image: Screenshot of modified checkbutton]

You should note that some of the elements pick up additional configuration attached to the style by the `ttk::style configure` command so when copying a style you should also copy the configuration:

```
ttk::style configure $new_stylename {*}[ttk::style configure $old_stylename]
```

and most likely also the map of widget states (`ttk::style map`).

Reading the ttk library files in `<Tcl/Tk folder>/library/ttk` should show quite a bit about how these things are put together. The vsapi.tcl file in particular does quite a bit of layout for Windows.

Comment: Perfect. This is what I am looking for.